# How to solve an explicit wait which isn't waiting long enough selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriverwait

I'm trying to program a sequence of events which are dependent on the last in selenium. First click login which loads a new page, then click a scrollbox on that page, then click a button inside the scrollbox which won't be loaded until the scrollbox has been clicked.

I am trying to stop using time.sleep(x) as I've read this is bad practice and I'm trying to learn more about how selenium works.

The code I've got that doesn't work is

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec

    login_box = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
        ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id=\"loginAppRoot\"]/div[1]/div[1]/button/span")))
    login_box.click()
    print("login")
    scroll_box = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
        ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id=\"searchBarFilterDropdown\"]")))
    scroll_box.click()
    box_inside_scroll = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
        ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id=\"global-header\"]/nav[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul/li[44]/a")))
    box_inside_scroll.click()
```

The only way that I can get this to work is to put a  `time.sleep(2)`  before `scroll_box.click()`. From my understanding the webdriver wait and expected condition should negate the need for me to use time.sleep. Could anyone help me to remove the pre-defined wait times?

Answer (score 0):

If you need selenium to wait longer you just have to change the timeout. If all you need is 2 seconds more then try

```
scroll_box = WebDriverWait(driver, 7).until(
        ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id=\"searchBarFilterDropdown\"]")))
    scroll_box.click()
```

when using WebDriverWait, in the parenthesis, your first input is your driver, second is the amount of time you want selenium to wait before it times out. Instead of 7 you can try 10, so it waits 10 seconds before attempting to click the scroll box.

Comment: So the problem isn't that I'm getting a timeout exception being raised. I think it is to do with the fact that ec.element_to_be_clickable is not a strict enough condition because it is being satisfied a few seconds before the page is being loaded. Thanks for any help you can offer :)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the timeout doesn't have any effect to me so here's another answer.

Not a good conduct, but it saves you time:

I want to click on the element "Circuit Breaker control", I need the page to be loaded, so I do

```py
    page_loaded = False
    while not page_loaded :
      try:
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 40).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Circuit Breaker control"))).click()
        page_loaded = True
      except:
        time.sleep(1)
```

The error I get when it is not waiting enough time:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <a data-toggle="tab" onclick="getSelectedTab('tab_cblbs_position')" href="#tab_cblbs_position">...</a> is not clickable at point (188, 254). Other element would receive the click: <div class="waitMe" data-waitme_id="100" style="background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);">...</div>
```

I hope it helps.